# Actions that become free after quotienting out their kernel

Tags: gr.group-theory, terminology, group-actions

Let $H$ be the kernel of an action of a group $G$ on a space $X$. Is there a term for the actions with the property that the action of the quotient group $G/H$ on $X$ is free?

Comment: The induced action of $G/H$ on $X$ is the image of the action of $G$ on $X$ under the homomorphism that defines the action, so you could say "actions with free image".

Comment: This also means that all points have the same stabilizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's called **effectively free** (see for instance [here, page 3](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~olver/di_/rel.pdf), Fels/Olver, *On relative invariants*).

Comment: Yves, many thanks!